# string validation in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to validate text-boxes in JQuery bit I want to use regex for this. As i am new to JQuery, can someone suggest me how regex can be used in JQuery to validate text string (where for e.g. regex is something like `^(?:[\\w\\s-])++$)?`

Comment: why don't you use a JQuery validation plugin may i ask?

Comment: what characters want you to allow? An empty string should be valid? Please be more specific

Comment: RegExp does have nothing to do with jQuery. Test the string returned by `.val()` with Javascript RegExp functions. A real good online tester with cheatsheet is http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/

Comment: i am looking through validation plugin but not sure how i can validate using regex.. I have my regex with me, just want to know how to use it in jquery. Thanks @kontur

Comment: Missunderstood you then - so you want recommendations for jQuery plugins that allow you to hand them a regexp by which to validate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript regex functionality does not require JQuery, it can be used whether you have JQuery loaded or not.

Here are two great resources for javascript regex:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

To fit this into JQuery:

```
if (/your regex/.test($("#textbox").val()))
{
    // Valid
}
else
{
    // Invalid
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.jquery4u.com/syntax/jquery-basic-regex-selector-examples/

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions aren't part of the jQuery framework, they're just part of javascript. To make them, either call the RegExp constructor, and pass your pattern as a string, or use the shorthand notation:

```
var newExp = new RegExp('^[0-9]{3,5}$');
//is the same as
var newExp = /^[0-9]{3,5}$/;
```

There is no need to escape backslashes twice in your example if you meant `\w` or `\s`. You might think about reading some tuts on regex, though as your pattern is, erm, flawed...